TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument, when executing stored procedure
I'm trying to insert data into MSSQL database table by executing a stored procedure using python script.
Here is my stored procedure -
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Test] 
( 
   @ProcessId INT
  ,@CreatedByUserName VARCHAR(12)
  ,@CreatedByMachineName VARCHAR(12)
  --,@CreatedTime DATETIME
  ,@NumberOfDataRows INT  
  ,@DataSource VARCHAR(300)
  --,@RefId VARCHAR(8)
  ,@Postpone DATETIME2
  ,@Deadline DATETIME2
  ,@NewBatchId INT OUT 
) 
  AS  
  BEGIN    
  INSERT INTO Test(ProcessId, CreatedByUserName,
  CreatedByMachineName, CreatedTime, Postpone, Deadline,
  NumberOfDataRows, DataSource, RefId)   
  VALUES(
   @ProcessId,
   @CreatedByUserName, 
   @CreatedByMachineName, 
   GETDATE(), 
   NULL, 
   NULL,
   @NumberOfDataRows, 
   @DataSource, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),
   CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4), 2)
)
  SET @NewBatchId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  RETURN 0; 
END 
GO

Here is my python code snippet.
with engine.connect() as conn:
                conn.execute(text("CALL Sp_Test(:ProcessId, :CreatedByUserName, :CreatedByMachineName, :NumberOfDataRows, :DataSource)"), ProcessId=process_code, CreatedByUserName=username,CreatedByMachineName=hostname,NumberOfDataRows=row_count,DataSource='Shared')

But when i try to run my script, it gives following error.

TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ProcessId'

I tried to pass the values as a dictionary as well. But the error is same.
params = {'ProcessId': process_code,'CreatedByUserName': username,'CreatedByMachineName': hostname,'NumberOfDataRows': row_count,'DataSource': 'Shared'} 
with engine.connect() as conn: 
conn.execute(text("CALL Sp_Test(:ProcessId, :CreatedByUserName, :CreatedByMachineName, :NumberOfDataRows, :DataSource)"),**params)

Appretiate if anyone could help me to figure this out?

@snakecharmerb I removed **. But now I get pyodbc programming error as 'sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")'

It might be better to try calling the procedure like this https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions - but I don't use SQL-Server so I can't provide any detailed suggestions I'm afraid.

For pyodbc you will need to use an anonymous code block as described here.

Note also that T-SQL (MS SQL Server's dialect) does not use CALL, it uses EXECUTE (often abbreviated to EXEC).

Have you noticed that none of the stored procedure parameters have default values? That means that they must all be specified when invoking the stored procedure. i.e.: if you try to EXEC dbo.sp_Test @ProcessId=1,@CreatedByUserName='username',@CreatedByMachineName='machinename',@NumberOfDataRows=1,@DataSource='shared'; from SSMS or DBeaver then you'll receive the error message, Procedure or function 'Sp_Test' expects parameter '@Postpone', which was not supplied.

As mentioned in a comment to the question, the pyodbc documentation for calling stored procedures that return OUTPUT variables and/or RETURN values is here. However, in your case you do not need to resort to a raw DBAPI cursor because your SP does not return result set(s) so you don't need to call pyodbc's .nextset() method. You can use SQLAlchemy directly, as in the following simplified example.
Given
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [BatchId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProcessId] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_test_sp]
@ProcessId int, @NewBatchId int OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Test (ProcessId) VALUES (@ProcessId);
    SET @NewBatchId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN 0;
END

we can do
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199")

with engine.begin() as conn:
    sql = """\
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @new_id int, @rtn int;
        EXEC @rtn = dbo.my_test_sp @ProcessId = :process_id, @NewBatchId = @new_id OUTPUT;
        SELECT @new_id AS new_batch_id, @rtn AS return_value;
        """
    result = conn.execute(text(sql), dict(process_id=123)).mappings().one()
    print(result)  # {'new_batch_id': 2, 'return_value': 0}


Thank you. This made my code run without error, and looks like the procedure gets called but data does not appear in the table. However, I get the NewBatchId returned correct for each insert. (same query works fine when called directly). This answer works for me but then I cannot use variable params dict so elegently. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

You can set engine.echo = True immediately before the with block and check the log output to see if a COMMIT is happening.

Thank you for engine.echo = True. Somehow the same code started working today.
